# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar una cookie que contiene una url para abrir una nueva ventana con window.location.assign()?

Tags: javascript, html, url, cookies, js-cookie

estoy empezando a estudiar javaScript y tengo problemas con un ejercicio que estoy desarrollando. He seteado una cookie en la que guardo una url. Esa url quiero pasarla dentro del método location.assign(url) para que me lleve a la página web a la que pertenece la url al apretar un botón.
Os pongo el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NUEVA VENTANA</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="nuevo_js.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="url">
    <button onclick="setCookie()">AÑADIR COOKIE</button>
    
    <button onclick="nueva(cName)">PAGINA NUEVA</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function setCookie() {
    let url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    document.cookie = "Nombre=" + url + ";path=/";
    alert(document.cookie);//para saber que funciona bien.
}


let cName = document.cookie;

function nueva(cName) {
    let posicion = cName.split(';');
        for(let i = 0 ; i < posicion.length ; i++){
            let url = posicion[1];
            location.assign(url);
        }    
}
```

Esto no funciona porque no reconoce correctamente la url de la página web así que me aparece el mensaje de "archivo no encontrado". Espero haberlo explicado bien.
Cualquier ayuda o aclaración será bienvenida. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el bucle no es necesario utilizar el bucle porque la url tendrá sólo dos posiciones separadas por un =. Entonces la función nueva() quedaría así sin pasarle ningún parámetro.

```js
function nueva(){
    let urlcookie = document.cookie; // ya tengo las coockie --> url_usuario = www.google.com
    let posicion = document.cookie.split("="); // separo en dos posicion["url_usuario","www.google.com"]
    let url = posicion[1]; // www.google.com
    location.assign(url); // recargo la pagina con el valor url igual a www.google.com
}
```